How to use functions that return the different types with interfaces in Go
I'm fighting with using interfaces, specifically where you have a function that returns the callers type.
So below:
type Foo struct {
    index string
}

func (f Foo) SetIndex(s string) Foo {
    f.index = s
    return f
}

We've got a simple setter, I'm intentionally not using a pointer as I want the struct to be immutable.
I then have an interface like below:
type Bar interface {
    SetIndex(s string) Bar
}

The below won't compile, as Foo doesn't implement Bar (needs to return Bar rather than Foo):
func main() {
    var test Bar
    test = Foo{} // error: Foo does not implement Bar
    test = test.SetIndex("test")
}

Now what I could do is update SetIndex on Foo to return Bar, but I don't want it to, as I may have other functions on Foo that I want to be able to call in the context after using SetIndex
So something like this won't compile:
*** updated ***
func (f Foo) SetIndex(s string) Bar {
    f.index = s
    return f
}
*****

func main() {
    var test Foo
    test = Foo{}
    test = test.SetIndex("test") // error: cannot use value of type Bar as Foo value
}

I could use type assertions to take this back to Foo, but this is a little messy to me, feels like I shouldn't need to cast it.
I could also maybe do something like the below, where I update the interface to return the specific struct:
type Bar interface {
    SetIndex(s string) Foo
}


But that defeats the point, as I want to have multiple structs supported, and the interface that I want to use to separate something is now implicitly tied to it.
The only other thing I've found that works with generic interfaces: https://go.dev/play/p/7luwt-eAd95
While this gets around the problem, doesn't feel like the natural thing to do. (Although when I think about it, this does make sense and seems the best answer without using pointers)
It feels like I'm missing something intrinsic here, anyone got any ideas?

Duplicate (the n'th). Interfaces must match verbatim, there is no contravariance in Go. This looks like a XY problem. Try to redesign. The "natural" thing would be to not return anything from your SetIndex Method. Also note that without pointer receivers your method implementations are moot.

Sorry can you elaborate on what you mean by 'Duplicate (the n'th)'? Apologies, my example is a little contrived, just I wanted to simplify the issue I was facing rather than a ton of noise for people to filter through. I'd love to use pointers but it's a fight I already lost in the past.

You really shouldn't be returning yourself. That's used in a chained function pattern that breaks as soon as you try to add error handling. Either return nothing (using a pointer for the method type), or better yet, export the variable so you don't need a setter at all. (You only want a setter when there's additional internal logic, validation, etc.)

This question is asked regularly (and I'm too lacy to keep a bookmark list for duplicates).

I see, I did search around but found nothing unfortunately, thanks though.

So you want a function that returns a copy of the receiver with changes. I use “With” instead of “Set” here, since this resonates more with the “copy” aspect.
As you mentioned above, you need to include the type in the interface (Go Playground):
type Nameable[T any] interface {
    WithName(name string) T
}

and you can use it in a function like:
func WithName[T any](nameable Nameable[T], name string) T {
    return nameable.WithName(name)
}

An example would be using these a name options:
func main() {
    var name Name
    name.Apply(
        WithName(GivenNameOption{}, "Peter"),
        WithName(SurnameOption{}, "Pan"),
    )

    fmt.Println(name)
}

type Name struct {
    given, sur string
}

func (n *Name) Apply(opts ...NameOption) {
    for _, opt := range opts {
        opt.apply(n)
    }
}

type NameOption interface {
    apply(name *Name)
}

and GivenNameOption, SurnameOption like:
type GivenNameOption struct {
    given string
}

func (g GivenNameOption) WithName(name string) GivenNameOption {
    g.given = name

    return g
}

func (g GivenNameOption) apply(name *Name) {
    name.given = g.given
}

type SurnameOption struct {
    sur string
}

func (s SurnameOption) WithName(name string) SurnameOption {
    s.sur = name

    return s
}

func (s SurnameOption) apply(name *Name) {
    name.sur = s.sur
}

This gives you “immutable” options, where you can use a generic function to get a copy with changed properties and which don't loose their type, so you can still use them as NameOption event though Nameable is not constrained by that.
I don't think this is very useful or much more than you have figured out yourself, but it is a complete example of “generic function returning a copy without loosing the type”.
